# Why i get no data in my table

Tags: ngtable

I can see the table but there are no values in there
heres is my Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/RKiEZkxTCJSYpmhR69cI/

I try for hours and cant find a way to do it...
Also i set mySQL to display only 3 results of ~800.000, will this be a Problem if i remove the limit? 
I want to paginate it anyway.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@4.0.0/bundles/ng-table.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as MC">
  <table ng-table="MC.tableParams" show-filter="true" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="x in $data">
      <td data-title="'Held'" sortable="'Held'">{{ x.Held }}</td>
      <td data-title="'Waffe'" sortable="'Waffe'">{{ x.Waffe }}</td>
      <td data-title="'Schild'" sortable="'Schild'">{{ x.Schild }}</td>
      <td data-title="'Ring'" sortable="'Ring'">{{ x.Ring }}</td>
      <td data-title="'Amulett'" sortable="'Amulett'">{{ x.Amulett }}</td>
      <td data-title="'Mantel'" sortable="'Mantel'">{{ x.Mantel }}</td>
      <td data-title="'ID'" sortable="'ID'">{{ x.ID }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-table@4.0.0/bundles/ng-table.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

APP

```
var test = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTable']);

test.controller('myController', function myController($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {

  $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
    page: 1, // show first page
    count: 5 // count per page
  }, {
    getData: function($defer, params) {

      $http.get('http://sanctuments.16mb.com/getData.php').
      $promise.then(function(data, status) {
        var orderedData = data;
        $defer.resolve(orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
      })
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally made it:

```
var test = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTable']);

test.controller('myController', function myController($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {
  var self = this;
  $http.get('http://sanctuments.16mb.com/getData.php').
  success(function(data, status) {
    self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({}, {
      dataset: data
    });
  });
});
```

Or better this one:

```
var test = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTable']);

test.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', 'NgTableParams',
  function myController($scope, $http, NgTableParams) {
    var self = this;

    $http.get('http://sanctuments.16mb.com/getData.php').success(function(data, status) {
      self.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
        page: 1, // show first page
        count: 10 // count per page
      }, {
        total: data.length,
        getData: function(params) {
          return data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
        }
      });
    });
  }
]);
```